# Color vector according to angle

Tags: plotting, color, vector

One can use the function `VectorColorFunction` in `VectorPlot3D` to color vectors according to their norms. How to color vectors according to the angle they are pointing along, say, in the x-y plane? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 VectorColorFunction -> (Hue@Rescale[Arg[#4 + I #5], {0, 2 Pi}] &), 
 VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `Arg[]`'s range is $(-\pi,\pi]$. ;)

Comment: @J.M. And the Plots are quite different, I see :)

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot of arguments in [`VectorColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorColorFunction.html). In your particular case you can write the following

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 VectorColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, v}, Hue[ArcTan[vx, vy]/2/π]], 
 VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: I was a bit slow... However, I believe this explicit function is more clear for OP.

Comment: Thanks a lot, ybeltukov, I will upvote your answer! Much appreciated.